# Current passing through two connected wires from different materials

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current, material-science

Does the current change when it passes from the copper wire to the aluminium wire or does its value stay the same?

Picture to illustrate the question

[image: Picture to illustrate it]

Comment: What would happen at the junction of the two materials if the current through the Al wire were less than the current through the Cu wire?

Comment: @AlfredCentauri The current will get stuck there? I don't know, that seems pretty impossible

Comment: I think you see the issue - if there is more current from the copper than in to the aluminum, charge *must* start accumulating there. But what is the effect of that accumulation of charge? Don't like charges repel?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the total voltage (potential) across the left and right ends of the conductors is $V$, then the current running through both connected wires is the same, say $I$.

Let the resistance of the copper part be $R_{Cu}$ and the resistance of the aluminium part be $R_{Al}$, then the total resistance is:

$$R=R_{Cu}+R_{Al}$$

With Ohm, we then have:

$$I=\frac{V}{R}$$